# Two "or" conditions for event?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, click, mouseup

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TKWzH/8/

The "Test Pop" is the current function of the item. "Test Pop 2" is what I would like my script to function as. However, the actual script has a lot more functions on the click execution than just closing the popup.

Is there a way to combine the on enter and on mouseup commands into one line?

```
$("#popup2 label").on('keyup || mouseup', function (event) {
    $('#popup2').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Something like that is what I'm looking for, but I want the key up to only function for enterkey keyup. As that is written, it happens for any key.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I want to make the form keyboard accessible. As you can tell from the fiddle, if you navigate through Test Pop with the keyboard, you have to reopen the dialogue after you select a radio button.

Comment: Radios can be selected using the spacebar as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a space.

```
$("#popup2 label").on('keyup mouseup', function (e) {
    if (e.type == 'keyup' && e.which != 13) return;
    $('#popup2').css('display', 'none');
});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> ```
>  .on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )
> ```
>
> **events** One or more *space-separated* event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

Comment: Thanks this works great! Though I had to tweak it to this:  
$("#popup2 label").on('keyup || mouseup', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'keyup' && event.which != 13) return;
    $('#popup2').css('display', 'none');
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#popup2 label").on('keyup mouseup', function (e) {
    if (e.type==='keyup') { //key was pressed
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Enter was pressed
            //Do something
            $('#popup2').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }else{
        //mouseup was the trigger
        $('#popup2').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

could be simplified a lot, but just to show how it's done!

Comment: There's no need to do the whole `e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which` dance -- jQuery normalizes events for you.

Comment: I don't want redundant code because there's a lot more happening than the style change. It's like a style change, and several other functions that are supposed to happen on click.